# Angular 2 form validation touched and dirty gives back error, can't find out why

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have implemented a custom form validation for changing password. It works good, but I'm getting an error message, when the new password is typed, but the confirmPassword is not touched yet, because the two differ. I want to use validation.dirty and touched, to prevent this behaviour, but implementing it as it follows, Im getting the following error:

`There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("mGroup]="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" [ERROR ->]#confirmPassword="ngModel">`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="changePassword()" [formGroup]="password">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="oldPassword">Old Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">New Password</label>
  <input formControlName="password" [formGroup]="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
  <input formControlName="confirmPassword" [formGroup]="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" #confirmPassword="ngModel">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.controls.confirmPassword.errors?.MatchPassword && (confirmPassword.touched || confirmPassword.dirty)">Password not match</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

I tought that `#confirmPassword="ngModel"` will solve this, on the `confirmPassword input`, but that's what causing the error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the code for `password: FormGroup` in your component.ts? What is it initialized to?

Comment: Also, what are your module imports?

Comment: Did you import the ReactiveFormsModule?

Comment: why are you mixing model driven and template driven approach ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working StackBlitz](https://angular-h7phbv.stackblitz.io) using "ReactiveForms" approach.

The first thing you are not doing right is mixing different form approaches.

If you want to use model driven forms (using `FormsModule`), then you need to get rid of the `ReactiveFormsModule` directives: `formControlName`, `formGroup`, etc.
Also, you missed the `[(ngModel)]="myValue"` in your code, which is required for `#ref="ngModel"` to work.

if you want to stick to ReactiveFormsModule, you need to get rid of `ngModel` code. Also, since you are using `formGroup` on the parent form, you DON'T need to specify it on the children:

```
<form [formGroup]="parent>
    <input formControlName="child">
</form>
```

would bind this form to:

```
parent = new FormGroup({
    child: new FormControl(null),
});
```

I also took the liberty to suggest a validation approach, where the "future" password field has MinLength and other validators, while the whole `password` FormGroup is responsible for making sure that your passwords match.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Custom Validator instead

**example:**

```
      ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
          password1: new FormControl(),
         password2: new FormControl('',this.comparePassword.bind(this)),

        })

   comparePassword(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
     if (control.parent){//
    const password1 = control.parent.value['password1'];
    const password2 = control.value;
      if(password1 === password2){
         return {passwordMismatch:true}
         }
     }
    return null;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password1">password1</label>
  <input type="password" 
   class="form-control" formControlName="password1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password2">password2</label>
  <input type="password"  class="form-control" 
  formControlName="password2">
    </div>
 <div *ngIf="myForm.get('password2').errors && myForm?.get('password2')?.errors?.passwordMismatch">
  Password Mismatch
  </div>
</form>
```

**[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactiveformvali-x1voxc)**